# Getting the angles of a non-right triangle when all lengths are known

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have a triangle that I know the lengths of all the sides. But I need to know the angles. Needs to work with non-right triangles as well.

I know it is possible, and I could have easily done this years ago when I was in trig, but it has completely slipped my mind.

Id prefer a solution that I can code into a function, or something that does not require constructing right triangles from it.

Comment: You should take a look at the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: Recall the cosine law: if $a,b,c$ are the lengths of the triangle and $\theta$ is the angle opposite $c$ then $c^2=a^2+b^2-2abcos\theta$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments, the formula that you're looking for is the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).
The three formulations are:
$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(C)$$
$$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 -2ac \cos(B)$$
$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos(A)$$

You can use this law to find all three angles. Alternatively, once you have one of the angles, you can find the next using the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), which states that:
$${\sin{A} \over a} = {\sin{B} \over b} = {\sin{C} \over c}$$

And of course, once you have solved for two of the angles, you need only subtract their sum from $180$ degrees to get the measure of the third.

Comment: @Théophile: (Now if we delete all these comments, *no one will ever know*...)